# How can I setup Meteor to work with Dreamweaver on Windows 7?

Tags: windows, meteor, dreamweaver

If I install Meteor on my Native Windows System is there a way to build a Meteor project using Dreamweaver (4.0+)?

I know I can use DW as an editor but I am wondering if I can preview the code dynamically on my browser from the IDE.

Comment: Is there a Windows IDE I can use flexibly with Meteor if DW is not an option?

Comment: Nitrous.io has a nice web-based IDE for meteor, node.js and others.  Code you write runs in a virtual development box though, not on your local windows box.

Comment: Official meteor tool has out of box support for build the project and none of IDE has support for build system as Meteor tool has.